# Random access file java

Tags: java, random-access

Im reading from a .csv file and I'm getting this weird numbers at the start of each line

12195820118109888100071.53 something like this, what do you think it could be my mistake

```
while ((line = bufRdr.readLine()) != null) {
    input = line.split(",");
    System.out.println(line);
```

That is what im using and printing each line. The first line is correct, but the second line onwards I see a string of numbers like this: `69363520177627835700077.119`. Help me please.

Comment: Could you please post (a sample) of the contents of the file?

Comment: Pls. post a complete working program with the file contents which reproduce the issue.

Comment: oh nevermind I found out what was the problem, thanks anyways@ david robinson and azodious

Comment: Well, it would be nice if you shared your insight with all of us.

Answer (score 2):

Normally CSV file content are separated by comma but in some case it could be tabulation delimited format, MySQL or excel generated format. You can use [Apache Commons CSV](http://commons.apache.org/csv/), it can handle DEFAULT,EXCEL,MYSQL or TDF  format of csv file. For Example -

```
Reader in = new StringReader("a,b,c");
for (String[] line : CSVFormat.DEFAULT.parse(in)) {
    for (int i = 0; i < line.length; i++) {
        System.out.println("value " + i + "=" + line[i]);
    }
}
```

- DEFAULT - Standard comma separated format
- EXCEL - Excel file format
- MYSQL - Default MySQL format
- TDF  - Tabulation delimited format